# Class name not working when called in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, psql

I have a webpage in which there is a form with diffrent elements, in that there is also a Textfield which searches the names from the database and display it in a dropdown fashion.

Below that there is one more field that which is a button , through which i can add new TextField , same as above.

In that newly added TextField, I want the same AutoComplete feature as done above.

I have given the class names all correct but it unable to fetch the Names and show it in a AutoComplete manner.

*NewUser.php*

```
<?php

 $db = pg_connect("host=hostname port=5432 dbname=dbname user=vnaem password=root");
 pg_select($db, 'post_log', $_POST);


 $query=pg_query("SELECT id,name FROM users_users");

 $json=array();

while ($student = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $json[$student["id"]] = $student["name"];
}

$textval = json_encode($json);
$foo = "var partnames=" . $textval;
file_put_contents('autocomplete-Files/NewEntryValues.js', $foo);


?>


     . . . . . . .  .

           <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Name: </label>  
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-2">
              <input id="partner_names[]" name="partner_names[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name" class="form-control input-md newentry" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

              $(document).ready(function() {
            var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
            var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
            var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

            var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increme

                    $(wrapper).prepend('<br><div style="margin-left:50px;"><center><div class="form-group"> <label class=" control-label" for="textinput" style="margin-left:327px;">Name: </label> <div > <input id="partner_names[]" name="partner_names[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name" class="form-control input-md newentry" style="margin-top: -25px;margin-left: 403px;width: 241%;">  </div>  <a href="#" class="remove_field"><img src="images/del24.png" style="margin-left: 810px; margin-top: -81px;"></a></a></div>'); //add input box\
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
        });

    . . . . . . . . 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="NewEntryValues.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
```

As you can see above, the class in Input Tag is newentry and in the Javascript also newentry,

I am fetch that **newentry** class name in a Another which takes care of Database connection and the AutoComplete Logic.

So , how can the get that logic working in this script tag too !

*autocomplete.js*

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';

var peopleArray = $.map(partnames, function (value, key) { 
    return { value: value, data: key }; });

    // Setup jQuery ajax mock:
    $.mockjax({
        url: '*',
        responseTime: 2000,
        response: function(settings) {
            var query = settings.data.query,
                queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
                re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
                suggestions = $.grep(peopleArray, function(search) {
                    // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                    return re.test(search.value);
                }),
                response = {
                    query: query,
                    suggestions: suggestions
                };

            this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
    });



    // Initialize autocomplete with custom appendTo:
    $('.newentry').autocomplete({
        lookup: peopleArray
    });
});
```

*NewEntryValues.js*

```
var partnames={"19":"ABCD","42":"group","103":"cv","104":"name_to_1","105":"livetest","106":"live2"}
```

I am using this [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) for reference

Comment: where is your autocomplete code?

Comment: I have updates the above question see

Comment: You are calling `autoComplete()` to `.newentry` while its not part of the DOM. You should call `autoComplete` after `$(wrapper).prepend()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing autocomplete on `.newentry` while your `.newentry` is not part of the DOM yet

```
// Initialize autocomplete with custom appendTo:
$('.newentry').autocomplete({
     lookup: peopleArray
});
```

`.newentry` comes into the picture in `$(add_button).click()` when you `prepend()` the `.newentry` in `wrapper`.

Initialize your `autocomplete` after adding `.newentry` in `wrapper`.

**Updated**

In NewUser.php,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var peopleArray = $.map(partnames, function (value, key) { 
        return { value: value, data: key }; 
    });

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increme

            $(wrapper).prepend('<br><div style="margin-left:50px;"><center><div class="form-group"> <label class=" control-label" for="textinput" style="margin-left:327px;">Name: </label> <div > <input id="partner_names[]" name="partner_names[]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name" class="form-control input-md newentry" style="margin-top: -25px;margin-left: 403px;width: 241%;">  </div>  <a href="#" class="remove_field"><img src="images/del24.png" style="margin-left: 810px; margin-top: -81px;"></a></a></div>'); //add input box

            //Initialize autocomplete here when it has become the part of the DOM
            $('.newentry').autocomplete({
                lookup: peopleArray
            });
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you add it and show me please, i am not getting it

Comment: @aiffin Check the code above. You need to initialize the `autocomplete` inside `$(add_button).click()`. Let me know if still you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize text input after it has been appended to DOM.When you use `.newentry` as selector it gets elements that are part of DOM currently, but not the elements that will be appended later.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. Carefully go through the code. It is a part of my previous code and it works wonderfully. I have got the values in text box but as you can see in my php code i have commented the code to get the values in a drop-down.

Your php file (autocomplete.php)

```
<?php 
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query = mysql_query("select name from test where name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY name ASC"); // Run your query
/*echo '<select name="taskname">'; // Open your drop down box

// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = $row['name'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Your HTML File:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() 
        {
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'autocomplete.php'
});
});
</script>
<td><input id="skills" name="taskname"></td></tr>
    <label for="skills">Task Name: </label>
    <input id="skills">
```

Comment: How is this in any way relevant to the question?

Comment: How and when did `php` came into view?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe it is not as you say but he is trying to achieve the same thing which I have. that is getting data from database and autocomplete in a drop down?

Comment: @sam please refer to the code above it is done in php, javascript and html

Comment: @JimmySehgal i did this before but my database as thousands of values so each time i can't make request to database so i , pulled it into a file and then i am searching on to it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan    , I have updated the Question just see to and tell me

Comment: @sam has the answer to the issue.

Comment: @JimmySehgal I hadn't refresh the page so I missed the last edit when php code was added. My bad.

Comment: @aiffin I have updated the code. check it once.
And thanks to RoryMcCrossan for referring as I might have closed the SO by then.